# Branch.io API keys created does not deep link, but links created in dashboard does

Tags: branch.io

the links i created on the dashboard works for deep linking, but the ones i created in the API does not (it works for directing to app, but does not deep link once clicked)

**LINKS:**

- API: https://og75.app.link/6lOctoHLLx\
- CONSOLE: https://og75.app.link/lb7RahUIFx

---

CODE:

```
HTTP.post("https://api.branch.io/v1/url", :params => {
  :branch_key => "KEY",
  # also tried not wrapping it in data
  :data => {
    :linkType => "questions",
    :question_id => 1
  }
  }).to_s
```

---

**CONSOLE:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alex from Branch.io: I'm afraid the syntax you're using to build this API call isn't familiar to me so I can't replicate locally yet.

However, a few things that might help:

1. You can inspect the contents of a link by appending `?debug=true` to the URL (e.g., `https://og75.app.link/6lOctoHLLx?debug=true`). If you do this with both of your links, you'll see the API version is missing the parameters you are trying to set, which is why you don't get correct deep link behavior. Now to figure out *why*...
2. Not knowing the syntax of the call you're using in this example, I'm wondering if the `data` object is malformed. However, this would usually result in a 400 error with no URL returned, so I'm a little bit puzzled. If you look at our documentation for [basic API link creation](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/branch-deep-linking-public-api#creating-a-deep-linking-url), you'll see the following cURL example:

*Note how the contents of the `data` object are actually pre-escaped*

```
curl -X POST \
\
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
\
-d '{"branch_key":"key_live_feebgAAhbH9Tv85H5wLQhpdaefiZv5Dv", "campaign":"new_product_annoucement", "channel":"email", "tags":["monday", "test123"], "data":"{\"name\": \"Alex\", \"email\": \"alex@branch.io\", \"user_id\": \"12346\", \"$deeplink_path\": \"article/jan/123\", \"$desktop_url\": \"https://branch.io\"}"}' \
\
https://api.branch.io/v1/url
```

Perhaps you could try a call with the `data` object set as a string, and see if your link comes back with all parameters set? I have no idea if this is valid code for what you're working with, but perhaps something like this:

```
HTTP.post("https://api.branch.io/v1/url", :params => {
  :branch_key => "KEY",
  # also tried not wrapping it in data
  :data => {\"linkType\": \"questions\", \"question_id\": "1"
  }
}).to_s
```

Comment: alex -> after several rounds of debugging, i realized that i needed to set         "$one_time_use": "" in order for this to work properly, even tho, at no point in the iOS code am i using this

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing, and thanks to tips from the amazing Branch support and the debugging tips from Alex above, I finally isolated the situation.

Basically, even tho i was not using this particular parameter in iOS, I needed to add this as part of the parameters.

```
    "$one_time_use": "",
```

Not doing so basically did not trigger my continueUserActivity - which is weird, even when it is the first time i am using it.

Comment: Hmm, this absolutely should _not_ be the case. If this is working for you...awesome! But there is no reason why setting this should be fixing the symptoms you're seeing — happy to help debug further if you're interested!

Comment: i know! i was very puzzled too! maybe it has to do with my specific implementaion... ;)

Comment: I actually suspect it may be something like adding a control parameter (anything beginning with `$`) is causing the system to parse input that would otherwise be considered invalid. This makes me nervous, because there is no guarantee that your implementation might not break in future without warning. If you have time, could you [submit an integrations ticket](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) for this so we can get to bottom of what is really going on?